# Calculate work hours between two dates with different work schedules

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working on a vacations sheet. I have the start and end dates of the vacations and I need to calculate the working hours in between.
I have found many answers on google, but my problem is that not everyday is a 8-hour workday. The working hours of each day depend on the day of the week, on the month and on the employee (not all employees have the same schedule). How can I incorporate this into the calculation?

Comment: Better [edit] your post & share some sample data along with expected results, also the category for has different work hours, otherwise has straight solution !!

Comment: Interesting problem, but without sample data, any effort is wasted.

Comment: You can try to provide a simple sample here.

Comment: how does the "not everyday is a 8-hour workday" schedule looks like?